# How to make skype like floating window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pZpF.png)i would like to design skype like floating window.
on left from website it will pop up like floating window(skype call window).
how to do this.?any help.

like this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly because your question is kind of... short and unclear - but if I'm right you want a div element that is a modal/popup.

You can try creating a `div` element and styling it with

```
position: absolute; // pos absolute so the element can float on top
top: 50%; // put it in the middle of the screen
left: 0; 
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-OFFSETpx); // hide it by making it go out of the window
transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out; 
width: your-width;
height: your-height;
```

You can hide the div by making the parent hide its overflow - `overflow: hidden`.
OFFSET value should be high enough for the div to be invisible. You can now use JS to add and remove classes that will have a transform value of `translate(-50%, -50%)` and `left: 50%` - that would center your div.